# Errors with colcon using ros2 tutorial

Tags: ros2, colcon, tutorial, ros-iron

I've installed ROS2 iron and am following the tutorial [here]https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html. I have followed the steps up to and including "Add some sources". For the next section, "source an underlay", I have assumed I need to run `source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash`
Then when running `colcon build --symlink-install` I see the following in multiple packages

```
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_executors
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_executors                     
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:158: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
```

Then when running `colcon test` I see

```
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_executors
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_executors                      

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
executors/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
executors/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.
```

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
I'm at a loss, what is the underlying issue? Is it problems with `colcon build`, `colcon test`, code or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've answered my own question. The next tutorial goes in to setting up workspaces and covers resolving dependencies, which seems to have fixed it.

```
# cd if you're still in the ``src`` directory with the ``ros_tutorials`` clone
cd ..
rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro iron -y
```

Comment: Yup, this is a common "beginner mistake." Your workspace directory contains a lot more than just the source code, which lives in `src/`. It's a little confusing at first, but as soon as projects grow to any appreciable size, the organization makes a lot of sense.

I wish you lots of success with ROS2!